# Stop video when clicking on a different RecyclerView item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I have a RecyclerView, where each item plays a video. I share one instance of `ExoPlayer`, and only play one video on the screen at a time. When a user taps on a video's thumbnail, it opens the player in a fullscreen dialog.

However, my current problem is that if a video is playing in RecyclerView item #1, and the user taps the video thumbnail in RecyclerView item #2, it plays the video of item #2 (which is correct), but I don't know how to stop the video/show a thumbnail for RecyclerView item #1 (since they clicked on #2).

Here is the relevant code from the `onBindViewHolder`:

```
holder.videoThumbnail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        holder.openFullscreenVideoDialog();
    }
});
```

Here is the `openFullscreenVideoDialog()` method in the view holder:

```
    public class PostViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, FullscreenVideoDialogFragment.FullscreenVideoDialogFragmentListener {
        public Post post;

        public ConstraintLayout contentView;

        public ImageView videoThumbnail;

        public HlsMediaSource hlsMediaSource;

        public PlayerView playerView;

        public PostViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);

            contentView = v.findViewById(R.id.content_view);

            videoThumbnail = v.findViewById(R.id.video_thumbnail);
            playerView = v.findViewById(R.id.player_view);

            setupVideoDialog();
        }

        private void setupVideoDialog() {
            mFullScreenDialog = new Dialog(context, android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen) {
                public void onBackPressed() {
                    super.onBackPressed();
                }
            };
        }

        private void openFullscreenVideoDialog() {
            mExoPlayerFullscreen = true;

            FragmentManager fm = ((FragmentActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager();
            FullscreenVideoDialogFragment dialog = FullscreenVideoDialogFragment.newInstance(post, hlsMediaSource, exoPlayer);
            dialog.setFullscreenVideoDialogFragmentListener(this);
            dialog.show(fm, "fragment_video_dialog");

            playerView.setPlayer(null);
        }
    }
}
```

At its most basic level, my question is: how do I change views from item #1 when a user taps on the video thumbnail in item #2?

Comment: share your code for FullscreenVideoDialogFragment class also

Comment: @HaiderSaleem FullscreenVideoDialogFragment should be irrelevant to this

Answer (score 0):

If you will play on every `recyclerview` item and every item has its `exoplayer` then you should have a variable in your model like `isPlaying` then in every click run a `for` loop in your data then set all of them false then set `isPlaying` to true for the position has been clicked then `notifyDataSetChange()` in the adapter to refresh the list.

you should also check `isPlaying` in your `onBindViewHolder` and set `exoplayer` state.